# Как автоматизировать извлечение данных из исходного кода веб страницы?

Tags: веб-программирование

Как автоматизировать извлечение данных из исходного кода веб страниц?

Comment: Совершенно непонятно, что вы имеете в виду и как вы пробовали решить эту проблему.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду парсить страницы?

Comment: Требуется создать программу на c# для автоматического добывания определённого текста из исходных кодов указаной пользователем веб страницы(айдишники и т. д.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну на чем писать - не самое принципиальное, а вот искать контент по ID можно используя YQL:

1) Пройдите по ссылке https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

2) В поле запроса введите:

```
select * from html 
where url='http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/638282/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B' 
and xpath='//div[@id="question-header"]'
```

3) нажмите на `Test` и получите:

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 1,
  "created": "2017-03-11T20:23:13Z",
  "lang": "ru",
  "results": {
   "div": {
    "id": "question-header",
    "h1": {
     "itemprop": "name",
     "a": {
      "class": "question-hyperlink",
      "href": "/questions/638282/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b",
      "content": "Как автоматизировать извлечение данных из исходного кода веб страницы?"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

4) Если результат вас устраивает то скопируйте `Endpoint` и используйте его при http запросе.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)))

Comment: Не за что, это комьюнити - специально для этого.
P.S. как вы понимаете надо с xpath чуть разобраться (лично для меня это самое сложное)

Comment: Постараюсь как-нибудь разобраться)) Ещё раз спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о сборе данных с интернет страниц, то необходимо написать программу которая имитирует пользователя, т.е. она "открывает" страницу, затем читает содержимое (парсит), анализирует данные и извлекает то, что вам необходимо. Если сбор данных происходит с разных сайтов, страниц, то это означает то, что "способ анализа" данных будет различен для каждой страницы.

Автоматизировать анализ страницы, в этом случае, не получится в 95% случаях, так как для каждой страницы нужно писать свой индивидуальный анализатор, но если речь идет об одной страничке и будучи написав один раз анализатор, можно автоматический "заставить" программу собирать данные, например ежедневно, ежечасно, по событию и т.д. таким образом автоматизируя процесс…